# Commenting lines in php to make it faster

Tags: php, comments

I have searched a bit and got to something that discusses the possible negative effect of having to many comments.

Found here:
[Do comments make the code run slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423344/do-comments-make-the-code-run-slower)

Upon researching I found that when running a script and coming across a comment, the server knows to ignore the line and move on to the next one.

Now when thinking about it a bit more I have wondered if it would then improve load times if all open spaces in a php document were passed as comments.

The rudimentary argument is that rather than searching through each line, searching for code but finding none, the server knows to ignore the line or open space.

Is there method to this madness or am I missing a key aspect in how code is interpreted?

Comment: An empty line is zero tokens. A comment is one token. But either way this is beyond micro-optimisation and more like femto-optimisation. You have more important things to worry about, like your data centre spontaneously exploding.

Comment: @Niet I realize this is a very nitpick type of question, however I am curious as to if this has an effect on the script, regardless of how much of one

Comment: Do you now that php-code is compiled/parsed into opcode? And this opcode is cached! http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.php While parse/complie all comments will be removed.